# C++ One file several classes

Tags: c++, class, dependencies

I want to keep two classes in one file and I want one of them to have instances of another inside. So in my header file I have something like this:

```
class Box{
    Item a,b,c;
    /*
    ...
    */
}

class Item{
    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

Obviously compiler says that it doesn't know what Item. How to make it see the Item class ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just move Item class definition on top of class `Box`. Now Box can see complete Item type and it's valid to be a member of Box.

```
class Item{
    /*
    ...
    */
}

class Box{
    Item a,b,c;
    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might forward declare your classes by adding at the start of your code:

```
 class Box;
 class Item;
```

Beware that the compiler should know the size of every data member of a class. You may want to reorder your classes definitions to ensure that, or use pointers, etc...

<sup>You might want to use raw pointers, references, smart-pointers, ...</sup>

Comment: This will not work in this case, precisely because of the reason you mentioned: compiler needs to know sizes of members.

Comment: "Beware that the compiler should know the size of every data member of a class." and if for the type T this is not possible you should use pointers and references to T to circumvent the problem.

Comment: @user2485710 Well, I would rather split the class declarations into two files rather then "circumvent the problem" by using pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Item{
    /*
    ...
    */
}

class Box{
    Item a,b,c;
    /*
    ...
    */
}
```